# Understanding the role of automatic variables in make/makefile

Tags: linux, macos, shell, unix, makefile

I've recently started learning about make/makefiles and some of its associated concepts. I have thus far created some basic versions, with targets, dependencies, actions, etc. However, I have been unable to make sense of what **automatic variables** are in this context, their utility, or how to use them.

I've done a lot of research on this topic. However, I haven't been able to locate any satisfying material. It seems that the most reputable source of information is [this GNU page](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables). However, I still do not understand exactly what automatic variables are, what their utility is, or how I can practically use them in my makefiles.

I am interested to find out what they are, what their utility is, and how I can practically use them.

Comment: Try editing your question to be more specific and concise.  I think you have at least three questions, and each is very broad.

Comment: @Jerry I just want an explanation of what they are, what their utility is, and how I can practically use them. An example would help to illustrate these ideas. I'm not looking for something highly elaborate. I'm just a newbie to this concept who is seeking clarification.

Comment: I edited the OP with what I stated in my above comment. Hopefully this will provide clarification and specificity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Automatic variables are simply variables for which the value is generated by Make, rather than having to be set explicitly.

If you take a look at existing Makefiles (pick your favorite open source project!), you'll find lots of practical examples to help you out.  A common one looks something like this:

```
%.o: %.c
    gcc -c -o $@ $<
```

This is a pattern rule that says "to build a file named `<something>.o`, which depends on `<something.c>`, use the command `gcc -c -o $@ $<`.  `$@` is an automatic variable that evaluates to the target of the rule, and `$<` is an automatic variable which evaluates to the first prerequisite of the rule.  These automatic variables are critical to this sort of pattern rule; they allow you to run `make foo.o` or `make bar.o` and have the appropriate values substituted into the command line.  E.g., if you type `make foo.o`, Make will try to run:

```
gcc -c -o foo.o foo.c
```

Or consider this example from [the git Makefile](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Makefile):

```
strip: $(PROGRAMS) git$X
    $(STRIP) $(STRIP_OPTS) $^
```

This is used to strip symbol information from object files.  It needs to operate on all of the prerequisites, so it uses `$^`, which evaluates to...a space-separated list of all the prerequisites.